# How do I set a lock screen wallpaper on the OnePlus One with the latest Android Update?

Tags: battery-life, wallpaper

Okay so previously on the home screen ,I'd press the menu button- wallpapers- lock screen wallpaper and select my image to set as the lockscreen wallpaper.I can't do that anymore after the lollipop update. And also battery has been draining out like crazy after I updated it. This needs to be fixed.

Comment: *And also battery has been draining out like crazy after I updated it. This needs to be fixed.* -- Asking multiple yet varied questions is deprecated on this website IMO. Please ask a new question [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), relevant to the  selected italic content. Also, please take a look at [how to search](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/searching)(on this website), since battery draining questions have been already discussed  multiple times (might even resolve the issue without asking).

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This is a partial answer and is meant to solve the Lock-screen wallpaper issue only.

---

One way of changing the lock-screen wallpaper in CM 12 (the update for OnePlus) is:

Go to **Settings → Themes** →tap the wrench icon in your current theme → scroll down to **Lockscreen Wallpaper** → **Pick Image** (*choose the image*) → tap Back button/key once and tap right icon to apply the custom theme. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Just touch the home screen for long and then select wallpaper, then there will come an option to change the wallpaper. Slide it to right side and there will come another option for lockscreen paper. Select the option from Gallery then you can change lock screen photo.