# How to hide Vibrate status bar icon on CM12?

Tags: cyanogenmod, oneplus-one

I just got my OnePlus One, running on CyanogenMod 12.1. This phone is great... However one thing bugs me, the vibrate status bar icon.

[image: home screen with vibrate icon][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBTZd.jpg)

It just makes my phone ugly! How can I hide it? Thanks.

Comment: Is the device rooted?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use a different theme's status icons. You're using Hexo theme's status icons as it seem at first glance. You can choose to change the whole theme or just the status icons by an other theme's status icons under **Settings → Themes**. [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/108874/96277) should help you out.

Try the icons of System (Android) theme or download others themes using **Themes** app (a system app).

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Right, that just changed the icon. I want to hide it completely.

Comment: That's why I asked. Is the device rooted?

Comment: Sorry. It is not rooted.